# Angular js/javascript count how many times an iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, iteration

I have my code below i wanted to know how will i get the count of all $scope.rm that is equal to failed or how many $scope.percentage < 50.

```
angular.forEach(result1, function (value, key) {

    $scope.percentage = (value.score * 100 / value.total).toFixed(2);

    if ($scope.percentage < 50) {
        $scope.rm = "Failed"
        $rootScope.sendmail = 0

    }else {
        $scope.rm = "Passed"
        $rootScope.sendmail = 1
    }

});
```

Comment: take a variable outside of forEach and assign it to zero
after that increment it when you get $scope.rm = "Failed" then you'll get no. of loop execution for that condition

Answer (score 3):

Take a variable outside of forEach and assign it to zero

after that increment it when you get $scope.rm = "Failed"

then you'll get no. of loop execution for that condition

for example:

```
var Failedcount=0,Passedcount=0;
angular.forEach(result1, function (value, key) {

       $scope.percentage = (value.score * 100 / value.total).toFixed(2);

                    if ($scope.percentage < 50) {
                        $scope.rm = "Failed"
                        $rootScope.sendmail = 0
                        Failedcount++;

                    }else {
                        $scope.rm = "Passed"
                        $rootScope.sendmail = 1
                        Passedcount++;
                    }

                });
console.log("failed counter",Failedcount)
console.log("passed counter",Passedcount)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var failedCount = 0;

angular.forEach(result1, function (value, key) {
  $scope.percentage = (value.score * 100 / value.total).toFixed(2);  

  if ($scope.percentage < 50) {
     $scope.rm = "Failed"
     $rootScope.sendmail = 0
     failedCount++;
  }else {
     $scope.rm = "Passed"
     $rootScope.sendmail = 1
  }
});

console.log(' total failed count : '+failedCount);
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to put a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Here I declared another variable to track the number of times it fails.

```
$scope.numberOfFails = 0
```

Then make it increment by 1 every time the fail condition is met, so it counts every time it fails.

```
$scope.numberOfFails = 0
angular.forEach(result1, function(value, key) {

  $scope.percentage = (value.score * 100 / value.total).toFixed(2);

  if ($scope.percentage < 50) {
    $scope.rm = "Failed"
    $rootScope.sendmail = 0
    $scope.numberOfFails++
  } else {
    $scope.rm = "Passed"
    $rootScope.sendmail = 1
  }

});
console.log($scope.numberOfFails)
```

After that, you will get `$scope.numberOfFails` as the correct number of times it has failed.